# Why @Autowired not working all the time?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, annotations

Im trying to setup mongodb with SpringBoot and im not using context.xml but trying to configure with configuration class and annotations.

```
package com.configuration;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.mongo")
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "mongodbname";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    }
    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.mongo";
    }
}
```

My repository looks like this :

```
package com.mongo.repositories;

import com.mongo.documents.Sequence;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository("sequenceRepository")
public class SequenceRepository{
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public Sequence findOne(Query query){
        return this.mongoTemplate.findOne(query,Sequence.class);
    }

    public List<Sequence> find(Query query){
        return this.mongoTemplate.find(query,Sequence.class);
    }

    public void save(Sequence object){
        this.mongoTemplate.save(object);
    }

    public void delete(Sequence object){
        this.mongoTemplate.remove(object);
    }
}
```

If i use like this in the rest controller it is working properly :

```
package com.controllers;

import com.mongo.documents.Sequence;
import com.mongo.repositories.SequenceRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
    private SequenceRepository sequenceRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
        sequence.setClassName("class.Test");
        sequence.setActual(1);
        sequenceRepository.save(sequence);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

But if i want to use the SequenceRepository inside the Sequence document like this :

```
package com.mongo.documents;

import com.mongo.repositories.SequenceRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Sequence {

    @Autowired
    private SequenceRepository sequenceRepository;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String className;

    private int actual;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    public int getActual() {
        return actual;
    }

    public void setActual(int actual) {
        this.actual = actual;
    }

    public void save(){
        this.sequenceRepository.save(this);
    }

    public void delete(){
        this.sequenceRepository.delete(this);
    }
}
```

After that I change the code in the controller to :

```
package com.controllers;

import com.mongo.documents.Sequence;
import com.mongo.repositories.SequenceRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
    private SequenceRepository sequenceRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
        sequence.setClassName("class.Test");
        sequence.setActual(1);
        sequence.save();
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I got a nullPointerExceeption at this point in the save() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to inject your Repository inside your Domain object `Sequence` as it is really bad design to have a dependency between the domain objects and your repository classes.

To follow some good practices, your `Service` classes or if you don't need a Service layer, your `Controller` classes should inject your Repository beans.

In your last code snippet your are already doing it, but the `.save()` method should be called on your repository `SequenceRepository` and not on the domain object `Sequence`.

An example could be the following:

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private SequenceRepository sequenceRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){

        Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
        sequence.setClassName("class.Test");
        sequence.setActual(1);


        // now let's save it
        sequenceRepository.save(sequence);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i dont want to use the repository layer in the controller? is there any way to hide it with another class?

Comment: yes, put a so called `Service` layer in between. So your structure looks like: controller -> service -> repository. Therefor you can create a SequenceService and inject it in your Controller. This is also a good practise to make your Repository calls in your Service.

Answer (score 1):

You can only autowire Spring-managed components into other Spring-managed components. Your sequence object is not a component (not annotated with @Component, @Service, @Repository or @Controller etc.)

I suggest you follow rieckpil's advice.